# Не получается написать скрипт создания функции в PostgreSQL через IDEA

Tags: sql, postgresql, intellij-idea

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_message (user_id INTEGER, message_id INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF messages
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM channels c
            JOIN messages m ON c.id = m.channel
            WHERE m.id = message_id AND user_id = ANY(c.users)
        )
        OR
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM channels c
            JOIN messages m ON c.id = m.channel
            WHERE m.id = message_id AND user_id = c.owner
        )
    ) THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT *
        FROM messages
        WHERE id = message_id;
    ELSE
        RETURN;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

IDEA ругается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если убрать `CREATE`, то подсветка ошибок пропадёт.

**UDP**: При запуске скрипта функция успешно создаётся всё равно.